# Entify Framwork Core one to one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having trouble in creating a simple one-to-one relationship using Entity Framework core.
The entities and the override of the OnModelCreating method look like this:

```
    public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public BlogImage BlogImage { get; set; }
}

public class BlogImage
{
    public int BlogImageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public int BlogForeignKey { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasOne(p => p.BlogImage)
            .WithOne(i => i.Blog)
            .HasForeignKey<BlogImage>(b => b.BlogForeignKey);
    }
```

When i pass the command Update-Database i get this error message:

```
Consider using the 'await' operator  to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) 
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) 
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean openConnection, Boolean closeConnection) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean manageConnection) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.DatabaseUpdateCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0() 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) 
ClientConnectionId:f21894a0-4ae6-4b73-95fc-40a7804cf9cb
 Error Number:156,State:1,Class:15
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
```

What should I check?
Thank you!

Comment: The model is ok. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Thank you Ivan Stoev for trying to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

I think. Usually because in one to one relationships entity framework can not infer foreign key and principal keys.

You should express them explicitly to ensure right foreign key creation.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                .HasOne(parent => parent.BlogImage).WithOne(child => child.Blog)
                .HasPrincipalKey<Blog>(parent => parent.BlogId).HasForeignKey<BlogImage>(child => child.BlogForeignKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for trying to help me.
It seems that the problem was related to the version of the SQL Server. I didn't know that EFCore is not compatible with SQL Server 2005.

Thank you!
Best regards!